# Why My Code didn't display Date (dd-M-yy format) in the input field after selected?

Tags: php, html, ajax

Below is my code.

Firstly, run the index.php Then there is a dropdown list will display and need to select a value from the dropdown. so far, dropdown will display value 1 or 2. If you select 2 it will display the value that has been selected together with the "date" field called from the display-date.php and from the "date" field, you may choose the date from calendar which called using datepicker plugin.

Now.. the problem is...I had select the date from calendar but the date selected didn't appear in the date input field. where am I wrong?

Hope anyone could help me please... :)

Thanks.

Here is index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      function getData(str){
          var xhr = false;
          if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
              // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          } 
           else {
              // IE5/IE6
              xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
           }
           if (xhr) {
               xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                  if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                       document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                   }
                }
                xhr.open("GET", "display-date.php?q="+str, true);
                xhr.send(null);
            }
       }
     </script>
     <div>
      <?php
         echo '<select title="Select one" name="selectcat" onChange="getData(this.value)">';        
         echo '<option value="None">-- Select Option --</option>';
         echo '<option value="1">One</option>';
         echo '<option value="2">Two</option>';
         echo '</select>';
       ?>
      </div>
      <br/><br/>
      <p>You selected: <span id="results"></span></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is display-date.php

```
<?php
$Q = $_GET["q"];
echo $Q;
?>

<?php
if ($Q ==  '2'){
?>

<html>
<head>
    <style>
         #date_input{
            text-indent: -500px;
            height:25px; 
            width:200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <input id ="date_input" dateformat="dd-M-yy" type="date"/>
    <span class="datepicker_label" style="pointer-events: none;"></span>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#date_input").on("change", function () {
     $(this).css("color", "rgba(0,0,0,0)").siblings(".datepicker_label").css({ "text-align":"center", position: "absolute",left: "10px", 
top:"14px",width:$(this).width()}).text($(this).val().length == 0 ? "" : 
($.datepicker.formatDate($(this).attr("dateformat"), new Date($(this).val()))));
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: I don’t use raw xmlhttprequest or actives because jquery makes it so much simpler; but I’m not familiar with using ajax in such an odd way. True, you can send html for insertion into the existing page, but you’re using it more like an html submit to go to another page. Ajax is primarily for transporting data, not for drawing web pages. If you want a datepicker, put it in the first page. If you want it hidden until you select option 2, use JavaScript to do so. That way all the elements are in the DOM, which very likely is one of the problems you’ve run into: `date_input` isn’t in the dom.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the **display-date.php** . Html base structure is no longer needed.

```
<?php
$Q = $_GET["q"];
echo $Q;
?>

<?php
if ($Q ==  '2'){
?>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <input id ="date_input" dateformat="dd-M-yy" type="date"/>
    <span class="datepicker_label" style="pointer-events: none;"></span>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#date_input").on("change", function () {
     $(this).css("color", "rgba(0,0,0,0)").siblings(".datepicker_label").css({ "text-align":"center", position: "absolute",left: "10px", 
top:"14px",width:$(this).width()}).text($(this).val().length == 0 ? "" : 
($.datepicker.formatDate($(this).attr("dateformat"), new Date($(this).val()))));
        });
    </script>


<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks.Yes this working but the date format is not as dd-M-yy

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no need to use ajax in your case, Ajax must not be used the way you showed in your question.
2. Ajax not used to draw html in DOM
3. No need to use ActiveXObject , It is insecure and I don't think we should support IE 5 or IE 6 anyways in modern development.
4. If you need to use ajax, Use JQuery's ajax function instead of XMLHttpRequest, As i see you are already using it.

Here is the code which works without ajax and works as it should be.

```js
function getData(str){
  $('.showInput').hide();
  $('.showText').text('');
  if(str != ""){

    str = parseInt($.trim(str));

    if(str == 2){
      $('.showInput').show();
    }else{
      $('.showText').text(str);
    }
  }

}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#date_input").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy' });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Demo</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    
  <style>
  .showInput{
   display:none;
  }
  </style>
     <div>
     
        <select title="Select one" name="selectcat" onChange="getData(this.value)">
   <option value="">-- Select Option --</option>
   <option value="1">One</option>
   <option value="2">Two</option>
        </select>
       
      </div>
      <br/><br/>
      <p>You selected: <span id="results">
  <span class="showText"></span>
  <span class="showInput">
   <input id="date_input" dateformat="dd-M-yy" type="text"/>
  </span>
 </p>
 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's Working! Thanks for helping :)